# Select de Select2 cambia pero inmediatamente se pone el valor por default

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

tengo el siguiente problema:
Tengo un formulario donde lleno datos de lugar (Municipio, localidad y colonia).
estos datos pueden ser traídos de otro formulario, para no tener que llenar los datos nuevamente.
Los datos se cargan bien, los muestro en la consola y si vienen bien.
el problema es que cuando hago el `trigger` para que cambie el select, cambia por un milisegundo y luego regresa al valor por default. Añado gif para que vean cómo se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando la librería de Select2, y según estuve leyendo, para que el cambio se aplique una vez que le asigné un valor debo hacer:

```
$("#miSelect").trigger("change");
```

y eso hago, el problema es que no se queda el cambio, solo se aplica al primero.
No se si tenga que ver el hecho de que estos selects son dinámicos, por ejemplo: El select de localidades cambia dependiendo del municipio seleccionado, y el de colonia cambia dependiendo de la localidad. Todos los datos se están cargando desde una tabla de mi base de datos. He pensado que tal vez es que cuando hago el trigger para cambiar el valor del select, aun no se ha cargado la info desde la base de datos.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué pueda estar pasando esto? les dejo mi código:

```
function copiDicIn() {
  let hayIn = $("#ExiIncGen").val();
  if (hayIn == "SI") {
    let municipio = $("#municipioInc").val();
    let localidad = $("#localInc").val();
    let colonia = $("#colInc").val();
    let calle = $("#calleInc").val();
    let numeroEx = $("#numeroInc").val();
    let numeroInt = $("#numeroIntInc").val();
    let entrecalle = $("#entreCaInc").val();
    let referencia = $("#refeInc").val();
    let coorX = $("#coorXInc").val();
    let coorY = $("#coorYInc").val();
    console.log(municipio + localidad + colonia);

    $("#municipioDet option[value='" + municipio + "']").attr(
      "selected",
      true
    );
    $("#municipioDet").trigger("change");

    $("#localDet option[value='" + localidad + "']").attr(
      "selected",
      true
    );
    $("#localDet").trigger("change");

    $("#colDet option[value='" + colonia + "']").attr(
      "selected",
      true
    );
    $("#colDet").trigger("change");

    $("#calleDet").val(calle);
    $("#numeroDet").val(numeroEx);
    $("#numeroIntDet").val(numeroInt);
    $("#entreCaDet").val(entrecalle);
    $("#refeDet").val(referencia);
    $("#coorX").val(coorX);
    $("#coorY").val(coorY);
  }
}
```

la info de los selects se carga de la siguiente forma(En un archivo aparte):

```
  /*  MUNICIPIOS */
  var opcion = 11;
  $.post("../../modelos/cargarSelect.php", { opcion: opcion }, function (res) {
    $("#municipioDet").html(res);
  });

  /*  LOCALIDADES */
  $("#municipioDet").on("change", function () {
    municipio = $(this).val();
    var opcion = 4;
    $.post(
      "../../modelos/cargarSelect.php",
      { opcion: opcion, municipio: municipio },
      function (res) {
        $("#localDet").html(res);
      }
    );
  });

  /*  COLONIAS  */

  $("#localDet").on("change", function () {
    localidad = $(this).val();
    var opcion = 5;
    $.post(
      "../../modelos/cargarSelect.php",
      { opcion: opcion, localidad: localidad },
      function (res) {
        $("#colDet").html(res);
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: Intenta con `$("#municipioDet").val(municipio); $("#municipioDet").trigger("change");`

Comment: Si lo había intentado, y no funciona. pasa lo mismo, se pone el valor por una fracción de segundo y luego regresa a "Seleccione"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el problema:
Tal parece que una vez que yo introducía la información al primer select y hacía el `.trigger("change")` para que apareciera seleccionada la opción, también estaba haciendo trigger al change que me carga la información desde la base de datos a los selects, por ende cada que daba click al botón, aparecía mi dato ingresado pero inmediatamente era reemplazado por el evento `change`.

Lo pude resolver cambiando el `.trigger("change")` por un `.trigger("change.select2")`
De esta forma se efectúa el trigger que me selecciona la opción deseada, y al mismo tiempo **NO** hace trigger al `change` que me carga la información en los Selects

Pero al no hacer trigger al change que trae la info de la base de datos, los selects quedaban vacíos, así que una vez que selecciono el valor deseado, cargo el siguiente select, y dentro del mismo `$.POST` establezco el valor que quiero seleccionado:

```
$("#municipioDet" + num)
      .val(municipio)
      .trigger("change.select2");

    var opcion = 4;
    $.post(
      "../../modelos/cargarSelect.php",
      { opcion: opcion, municipio: municipio },
      function (res) {
        $("#localDet" + num).html(res);
        $("#localDet" + num)
          .val(localidad)
          .trigger("change.select2");
      }
    );

    var opcion = 5;
    $.post(
      "../../modelos/cargarSelect.php",
      { opcion: opcion, localidad: localidad },
      function (res) {
        $("#colDet" + num).html(res);
        $("#colDet" + num)
          .val(colonia)
          .trigger("change.select2");
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

nose donde declaras el manejo del evento change pero asegurate que se declara antes del desencadenante.Ejemplo:

```
$('.check').change(function(){
  var data= $(this).val();
  alert(data);            
});

$('.check')
 .val('two')
 .trigger('change');
```

Comment: no estoy declarando ningun evento change. lo que hago es que le asigno el valor al select, y luego hago el trigger para que se refleje el cambio. O te refieres al evento change en el que cargo las localidades dependiendo del municipio? porque de ser así, eso está declarado en otro archivo separado.

Comment: Me refiero a lo segundo.

Comment: Bueno, pues eso está declarado en otro archivo. Debería volver a declararlo dentro de esta función?

Comment: Prueba para ver si así funciona.

Answer (score 0):

La librería `select2` trata de sincronizar los datos del tag `select` on una bonita interfaz hecha con otras etiquetas, creo que el problema está al tratar de cambiar el atributo `selected` de la etiqueta `option` en lugar de modificar el valor de la etiqueta `select`

El arreglo es cambiar el valor del select:

```
$("#municipioDet").val(municipio);
$("#municipioDet").trigger("change");
```

Comment: si intenté hacer eso, pero no funcionaba. agregué una respuesta con el cómo lo solucioné, era por el trigger del change